# Infragistics UltraGrid filter for dataRowError

Tags: c#, filter, infragistics, datarow, ultrawingrid

Using Infragistics.win.UltraGrid, I'm setting dataRowError for certain rows where I want the user to review. Everything looks good, I get a little red icon in the selector column with the proper tooltip; however, I need my user to be able to filter that column to only see the rows with errors.

Is this possible?

Thanks.
Mike

Answer (score 2):

You can change the FilterOperandDropDownItems from its default value to this one

```
grid.DisplayLayout.Override.FilterOperandDropDownItems = FilterOperandDropDownItems.All;
```

After this, your users will be able to see an 'Errors' option (as well a 'Non Errors' one) in the filter dropdown

[There is a tutorial](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/WinForms/2012.1/CLR2.0/HTML/WinGrid_Filtering_Rows_with_Errors.html) on the Infragistics site about this.

Comment: no - I need this in the column that shows an arrow if the row is selected... not in the actual columns.  Im only setting the error on the row, not on any cells?